# How to check if a module included with `include(...)` by cmake, exists?

Tags: cmake

In one of my CMakeLists.txt file I do:

```
include( AICxxProject )
```

and under certain circumstances (wrong installation) this gives:

```
CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:1 (include):  
  include could not find load file:  

    AICxxProject
```

I'd like to tell the user what they did wrong and how to fix it
with a `FATAL_ERROR` message. But, how can I detect if a module
like `AICxxProject` is going to be found before `include`-ing it?

Answer (score 2):

Solved by actually reading the documentation of [include](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include.html).

The following works,

```
include( AICxxProject OPTIONAL RESULT_VARIABLE _module_path )                                                                                                            
if ( NOT _module_path )                                                                                                                                                  
  message( FATAL_ERROR                                                                                                                                                   
      "include could not find load file: AICxxProject\n"                                                                                                                 
      "1) Make sure that you have the git submodule https://github.com/CarloWood/cwm4 in the top-level directory.\n"                                                     
      "2) Use `include(cwm4/cmake/AICxxProject)` right below the `project(...)` command in your top-level CMakeLists.txt."                                               
  )                                                                                                                                                                      
endif ()
```

with as output

```
CMake Error at cwds/CMakeLists.txt:9 (message):
  include could not find load file: AICxxProject

  1) Make sure that you have the git submodule
  https://github.com/CarloWood/cwm4 in the top-level directory.

  2) Use `include(cwm4/cmake/AICxxProject)` right below the `project(...)`
  command in your top-level CMakeLists.txt.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```